# Greek/Roman play in which a woman encourages a pregnant slave to marry a slave owner and pass her baby off as his?

Tags: identification-request

I can’t for the life of me remember which play this is, or indeed whether it’s Greek or Roman. There’s presumably a lot more to the plot than this, but all I remember is that a young woman is sold into slavery while pregnant, and an older midwife figure who has been bribed by a foreman, encourages her to marry him and pretend the baby is his.